# ARC apps crash with google chrome 45

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-arc

today when testing android apps with the arc runtime, which for some reason updated without me noticing. and all I get is that it immediately crashes.
I have tried repacking using the arc welder which is somehow also updated with no results.

UPDATE: since i did not see any progress on the stable channel i tried this on canary channel to see what might be causing the crash and found the errors "plugin not ready" and "plugin crashed: captured minidump" is there a way to solve these errors?

Comment: Same here, but only on the developer channel.... Instagram crashes on the developer channel: Version 47.0.2503.0 dev (64-bit)
This does not happen on the stable version: Version 45.0.2454.85 (64-bit) UPDATE: Now both crash... And it's only Instagram...

Comment: here is the issue page https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528652

Comment: feel free to comment on the issue on the comment above to give more insight on the problem

Comment: does it works now? for me it still doesn't for any apps i try. are there apps for which it works?

Comment: Instagram is still crashing... Some versions: Chrome: Version 48.0.2541.0 dev (64-bit), ARC Welder 48.5021.523.0, App Runtime for Chrome (Beta) 48.5021.523.0, Instagram 7.9.2

Comment: can you also comment on the issue page it appears they still haven't confirmed it as a bug here it is:https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=528652

Comment: appearantly others can't access the page my bad, maybe you can submit your own?

Comment: I can't access that page... And I should not duplicate the issue....

Comment: yes i noticed like i said in my previous comment, maybe if you duplicate the issue it'll help with confirming the bug?

Comment: As of 30/01/2016 this problem has not been solved... Instagram is still crashing...

Comment: Yeah that's true do you have a crash id? Maybe I can send it in the issue since strangely enough they still haven't confirmed the issue

Comment: No. Not sure how to get that... But I have the console output: http://i.imgur.com/uo8Xxnm.png

Comment: I'll start by sending that they said sum something about chrome://crash but I didn't see anything on my computer

Comment: When I go to that page it crashes the tab.... I think I found the
crash id: 1b4f456000000000
If you go to the extensions page: chrome://extensions/ then find "Instagram"  and click in "Errors" and scroll down you can see this: http://i.imgur.com/y3TdXRj.png send them my crash id and yours.... 
I'm running Linux Mint 17.3 64-bit Chrome 49.0.2623.23 dev (64-bit)

Comment: Hi @fuseteam
Any response from them? Did you send my crash id?
Thanks.

Comment: Yes I send your crash sadly still no response

Comment: As of today Instagram and other apps still don't work, so I opened a bounty...

Comment: They finally reacted though they act as if Instagram is the only app not working

Comment: https://blog.chromium.org/2016/08/from-chrome-apps-to-web.html?m=1 this seems to be the reason they didn't even bother :V