# chrome canary ARC apps not running

Tags: google-chrome-arc

I have installed chrome canary and added the ARC Welder. I see an warning of not running ARC welder on chrome OS. When I add an APK to test I see an error "uncaught TypeError:chrome.runtime.getManifest is not an function ". How do I solve this error?
UPDATE:i don't see this error anymore the only errors i see now are "plugin not ready" and "plugin crashed:captured minidump".

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you are using also the Canary version of the ARC Welder and ARC Runtime environment. Because it's a canary version there will be bugs in it. Chances are that the next day the error will be gone.

Comment: i guess you're i don't see the error but the all ARC Welder apps still seem to crash the only error i seem to get are: "plugin not ready" and "plugin crashed: captured minidump" these ARC Apps also seem to crash on the stable channel(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32408792/arc-apps-crash-with-google-chrome-45-and-google-chrome-canary-47) which is the original reason i tried the canary channel

Comment: there does not seem to be any update on this issue, does it works for some people if yes which applications?